# Switch case in where clause oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a below scenario. Could you please correct the below query..

```
 where l.au=m.acad_group

 and l.acad_prog = m.acad_prog

 case when acad_plan is not null then and l.acad_plan = m.acad_plan else and 0=0 
 end case

case when l.acad_sub_plan is not null then and l.acad_sub_plan=m.acad_sub_plan 
else and 0=0 end case;
```

Comment: `JOIN` conditions should be in the `ON` clause not the `WHERE` clause.  Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I've removed the PL/SQL tag. PL/SQL is the programming language in the Oracle DBMS used for triggers, functions etc., but your query is merely on SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct,You can use `OR` and `AND` instead of `CASE WHEN`

you can try this.

I have a little question on `acad_plan is null`, which `acad_plan` did you want to check  `l.acad_plan` or `m.acad_plan`?

```
where l.au=m.acad_group 
AND l.acad_prog = m.acad_prog
AND (acad_plan is null  OR( acad_plan is not null AND l.acad_plan = m.acad_plan))
AND (l.acad_sub_plan is null  OR( l.acad_sub_plan  is not null AND l.acad_sub_plan=m.acad_sub_plan))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `CASE WHEN` in the `WHERE` clause. Use `AND` and `OR` and parentheses.

```
where l.au = m.acad_group
  and l.acad_prog = m.acad_prog
  and (and l.acad_plan = m.acad_plan or l.acad_plan is null)
  and (and l.acad_sub_plan = m.acad_sub_plan or l.acad_sub_plan is null)
```

Comment: There are valid uses of a CASE in a WHERE clause, especially to force Oracle to run one predicate before another (eg check a string only contains digits before doing a TO_NUMBER on it )

Comment: @Gary Myers: That's true, although I'd rather write an exception-safe function for such case. For the particular case of `TO_NUMBER` we can even use the `ON DEFAULT` Option as of Oracle 12c.